# Unix Korn shell retrieve the latest file name with space

Tags: shell, unix

In my korn shell script until now I was trying to retrieve the latest file which didn't have spaces using this command and was working fine

```
ls -t TEST1_Qa_20170106.txt| head -1
```

But, now need to retrieve the latest file which is having the space in the file name (there is space between TEST and Qa). I tried the below but is not working.

```
ls -t TEST Qa_20170106.txt.pgp | head -1
```

How to get the latest file with space in it??

Comment: Shouldn't the pattern that you give to `ls` contain at least one file globbing character? As it stands now, even with double quotes added around the filename in the second example, you're just getting one file, and the `head -1` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use a quote around the filename.  Something like

```
ls -t "TEST Qa_20170106.txt.pgp" | head -1
```